# Unable to install pip using python on unix

Tags: centos, pip

I'm trying to install pip module for python using the command `python ./get-pip.py -v` but it returns an error that zlib is not available:

```
[root@centos1 yum.repos.d]# python ./get-pip.py -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "./get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "./get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

When I tried to query for zlib, I see that it's already present:

```
[root@centos1 yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep --color=auto -i 'zlib'
zlib-devel-1.2.3-7.el5
perl-Compress-Zlib-1.42-1.fc6
zlib-1.2.3-7.el5
perl-IO-Zlib-1.04-4.2.1
```

I tried installing zlib-devel, but still get the same error:

```
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

How do I fix this and proceed in installing pip, as i've a need to proceed with the installation of awscli.

Answer (score 2):

After installing "zlib" manually, after reinstall python again.

```
git clone https://github.com/madler/zlib.git 
cd ${ZLIB_CLONED_DIR}
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

Rebuild the Python from source again

```
cd ${PYTHON_SRC_CODE_DIR}  
./configure --prefix=${PYTHON_HOME_DIR}
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: can you give an example of what PYTHON_SRC_CODE_DIR and PYTHON_HOME_DIR look like? I find python in several folders and I don't know which wold be source code and/or home directories. I tried to do this but I am still getting zlib not available. I'm very familiar with Python installations on Windows but I am lost on Linux with several failed attempts to install anything above 3.5 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

the package `python-pip` is available in epel repo, install it by running `yum install python-pip -y` it will resolve any dependencies as well

after installing you can self update pip

`pip install --upgrade pip` then you can install awscli, `pip install awscli`

Comment: Matt, i should have done this before.. I tried to un-install and re-install python, but when i removed python, it removed all the additional packages and when i reboot my centos5, it crashed.. Then i had to rebuild a new centos6 version to continue with pip installation..